# Running Space Empires IV in windowed mode

Tags: space-empires-4

The game Space Empires IV uses DirectX 8.1 and I'm running it on Windows 7; it will run with a 800x600 or 1024x768 UI at the native resolution with letterboxing. How do I run it in Windowed mode?

Answer (score 2):

Go to the [official Space Empires IV downloads sites](http://www.spaceempires.net/downloads-cat-8.html) and then go to Page 3 (page select is at the very bottom). There on the bottom of the last page is a program called `Windowed SE4 Tool`:

> Task bar tool that causes SE4 to run in pseudo-windowed mode. Also contains handy shortcuts, such as shift-click to add 10 copies of a component to a design (or ctrl for 50).

Otherwise try posting your question on the [official Space Empires IV forum](http://www.spaceempires.net/forum-4.html).

Comment: I didn't spend much time on it but the tool didn't work for me. I'll upvote the answer, but I'm not going to accept it just yet. Thanks for finding this :)

Comment: Welp, the _only_ other thing I can think of to try would be to find out what _engine_ the game is using (I already spent some time trying). Then find other games based on that engine and see if there is an option to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the standard DirectX full-screen toggle hotkey?

Hold `Alt` and press `Enter`.

Otherwise check for any `.ini` or `.cfg` files (or anything text-based - anything < 4k is a suspect) in the main installation directory. Try opening them in Notepad and look around for keywords like `screen` and `resolution`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but unfortunately this was ineffective.